# Python brentq problems

Tags: python, scipy, data-fitting

I'm using lmfit to find confidence intervals for a fit but it keeps giving me an error every so often: `ValueError: f(a) and f(b) must have different signs`

Here is a minimal working example (run it a few times to get the error):

```
import lmfit
import numpy as np

def residual(p, X):
        a1, a2, t1, t2 = [i.value for i in p.values()]
        return a1*np.exp(-x/t1)+a2*np.exp(-x/t2)-y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.linspace(0.3,10,100)
    y = 3*np.exp(-x/2.)-5*np.exp(-x/10.)+0.2*np.random.randn(x.size)
    p = lmfit.Parameters()
    p.add_many(('a1', 5), ('a2', -5), ('t1', 2), ('t2', 5))
    mi = lmfit.minimize(residual, p, args=(x,))
    lmfit.printfuncs.report_fit(mi.params, show_correl=False)
    ci, trace = lmfit.conf_interval(mi, sigmas=[0.68,0.95], trace=True, verbose=False)
    lmfit.printfuncs.report_ci(ci)
```

Why does it do this? Is there a work around?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a specific answer or workaround.

I would report it as an issue https://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py/issues .

The confidence intervals are calculated by finding the point at which the profile likelihood equals a value. This requires to find the zero or root of a nonlinear function.
This method provides usually more accurate confidence intervals than relying on the local derivatives, like scipy's curve_fit for example.

It is in general tricky to specify bounds for scipy's brentq that work for all cases. My guess is that the default bounds are too tight for your example.

I only have a general idea about the method but don't know the specific code in lmfit.

Comment: That seems to be pretty much what's happening. What would be the definition of tight bounds?